# Python ignore \x00\x00\x00\x00

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I am parsing a list of items, and \x00\x00\x00\x00... is in it. I want to skip this.

I have tried the following code:

```
if "\x00" in item:
     pass
```

This doesn't work, and it still reads it. How do I ignore \x00?

Full code is here: https://github.com/codywd/NetGUI/blob/master/main.py lines 281-292 is where I try to skip it.

Comment: You'll need to give us more context, preferably a reproducible sample. *This doesn't work* is not enough of a problem description.

Comment: A full project file is **not** a reproducible sample.

Comment: I posted the entire program from github. Hopefully this shows the code in full.

Comment: What does `print(ascii(network))` show when it isn't being skipped but should be?

Comment: Random guess: have you tried using `continue` instead of `pass`?

Comment: When I can get this to show again (it doesn't show always), I will try and see. It mainly shows at my work.

Comment: If it's in a loop then replace `pass` with `continue`, which will cause the current loop iteration to be skipped.

Comment: pass works for the line before, if network == "". I will try continue when this shows up again.

Comment: Just to be clear: `pass` does absolutely nothing. If you have `if a: b(); else: pass`, you may as well delete the `else` clause entirely. And if you have `if a: pass; else: b()`, you may as well just write `if not a: b()`

Comment: @Kevin: it may be that other code still needs to run. The code can be simplified to `if network and '\x00' not in network:`.

Comment: The question _"Python ignore \x00\x00\x00\x00"_ is probably interesting, but please edit your question to **focus on that issue**.

Comment: use `os.path.mkdir`, and `os.path.join` to join paths instead of `+`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters print(ascii(network)) returns the following: '\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'

Continue also does nothing.

Comment: @CodyDostal: those are literal 4-character sequences of backslash, `x` and two `0` characters. `r'\x00' in network` will be true.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That was the answer!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pass` means nothing happens. It won't influence your code at all, the only place to use it really is if you want to execute a conditional but do nothing with it.

For example, here, `pass` does nothing and hello will still be printed.

```
if True:
    pass
    print "hello"
```

Here, pass is a placeholder for except. Python expects an indented line to do something, but if you don't want to do anything with the except, you can use `pass`.

```
try:
    int(5) + str(5)
except:
    pass
```

`Continue` is what you want, because it means proceed to the next iteration and don't proceed with the rest of the code.

```
r = csv.reader(tsv, dialect='excel-tab')
aps = {}
i = 0
for row in r:
    network = row[2]
    print(network)
    if network == "":
        continue
    elif "\x00" in network:
        continue
    else:
        aps["row" + str(i)] = self.APStore.append([network, "", "", ""])
```

***Edit:***

If you want to execute the `aps[...]` line, why not just do this:

```
if not "\x00" in network:
    aps["row" + str(i)] = self.APStore.append([network, "", "", ""])
```

Comment: Which means the rest of the row processing is skipped while the only thing the OP wanted skipped is the `aps[...] = ...` assignment.

Comment: Oh, I see. My mistake, I added another option in an edit.

Comment: `if network and "\x00" not in network:` is more pythonic; the CPython compiler rewrites the line, because it uses just one operator instead of two. You also need to test for the empty value.

Comment: "if not "/x00" in network" does not work either :(

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: It continues to put the network "/x00/x00/x00/x00..." in there.

Comment: I had to use r"\x00" instead of "\x00" to skip the network, per what @MartijnPieters said. Thanks to the both of you!